# Leaking memory with Cocoa garbage collection

Tags: cocoa, garbage-collection

I've been beating my head against a wall trying to figure out how I had a memory leak in a garbage collected Cocoa app. (The memory usage in Activity Monitor would just grow and grow, and running the app using the GC Monitor instruments would also show an ever-growing graph.)

I eventually narrowed it down to a single pattern in my code. Data was being loaded into an NSData and then parsed by a C library (the data's bytes and length were passed into it). The C library has callbacks which would fire and return sub-string starting pointers and lengths (to avoid internal copying). However, for my purposes, I needed to turn them into NSStrings and keep them around awhile. I did this by using NSString's initWithBytes:length:encoding: method. I assumed that would copy the bytes and NSString would manage it appropriately, but something is going wrong because this leaks like crazy.

This code will "leak" or somehow trick the garbage collector:

```
- (void)meh
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"holmes" ofType:@"txt"]];
    const int substrLength = 80;

    for (const char *substr = [data bytes]; substr-(const char *)[data bytes] < [data length]; substr += substrLength) {
        NSString *cocoaString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:substr length:substrLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [cocoaString length];
    }
}
```

I can put this in timer and just watch memory usage go up and up with Activity Monitor as well as with the GC Monitor instrument. (holmes.txt is 594KB)

This isn't the best code in the world, but it shows the problem. (I'm running 10.6, the project is targeted for 10.5 - if that matters). I read over the garbage collection docs and noticed a number of possible pitfalls, but I don't think I'm doing anything obviously against the rules here. Doesn't hurt to ask, though. Thanks!

[Project zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/545670/Meh.zip)

Here's a pic of the object graph just growing and growing:

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to see any leak when I run it, it hovers between 7.5MB and 9MB of memory usage after several minutes of running.

Comment: That's weird. I'm on 10.6.2. I built in debug and release. I see the ever-growing-memory in all cases. wtf...

Comment: I've now had someone else on 10.5 run it, and he reports that it doesn't seem to be growing for him, either. I need to get someone else on 10.6+ to try it.

Comment: running with the "leaks" instrument I don't get a leak, using the "object alloc" one gives the behaviour observed by Bryan

Comment: I think the leaks instrument is pretty meaningless with garbage collection, but I could be wrong. Erik/Bryan, were you on 10.6 or 10.5?

Comment: After watching it run for a lot longer, around the 1.5 minute mark there was a sudden drop in the memory usage. It must have initiated a deeper garbage collection. After letting it run for over 5 minutes, it has been repeating this pattern pretty consistently. However even with the drops, it is still building over all. Activity Monitor is reporting over 100MB of real memory presently. (Running 7 minutes now.) The GC Monitor reports 270MB in use (when I drag the playhead to see the numbers).

Comment: sorry, I was using the "gc" instrument, osx 10.6.2 && xcode 3.2.1. And I see the same pattern as you. It seems to be allocs in +[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:] that are kept for some reason. Does it have a cache perhaps?

Comment: Interestingly, ObjectAlloc's Live Bytes grows and grows until those heavier GC events (I guess) where it seems to reset and start growing again. It claims (after 11 minutes, now) that there's only about 32MB of live bytes. Is this a memory fragmentation issue, maybe? If so, though, it shows no sign of stopping it's consumption of more and more real memory from the OS. And the object graph still trends upward...

Comment: Leaks works fine under GC on Snow Leopard, BTW.  However, it tends to not show stuff that is garbage, but not yet collected.  This is purely a threshold related issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is an unfortunate edge case.  Please file a bug (http://bugreport.apple.com/) and attach your excellent minimal example.

The problem is two fold;

- The main event loop isn't running and, thus, the collector isn't triggered via MEL activity.  This leaves the collector doing its normal background only threshold based collections.
- The data stores the data read from the file into a malloc'd buffer that is allocated from the malloc zone.  Thus, the GC accounted allocation -- the NSData object itself -- is really tiny, but points to something really large (the malloc allocation).  The end result is that the collector's threshold isn't hit and it doesn't collect.  Obviously, improving this behavior is desired, but it is a hard problem.

This is a very easy bug to reproduce in a micro-benchmark or in isolation.  In practice, there is typically enough going on that this problem won't happen.  However, there may be certain cases where it does become problematic.

Change your code to this and the collector will collect the data objects.  Note that you shouldn't use `collectExhaustively` often -- it does eat CPU.

```
- (void)meh
{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"holmes" ofType:@"txt"]];
    const int substrLength = 80;

    for (const char *substr = [data bytes]; substr-(const char *)[data bytes] < [data length]; substr += substrLength) {
        NSString *cocoaString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:substr length:substrLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        [cocoaString length];
    }
    [data self];
    [[NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] collectExhaustively];
}
```

The `[data self]` keeps the data object alive after the last reference to it.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and possible workaround. Filed radar://556417.